# Could a black hole and a white hole cause gravitational waves, if orbiting one another?

Tags: visible-light, black-holes, gravitational-waves, gravitational-lensing, white-holes

I have been puzzled by an idea that I came across while reading about white holes.
But I've only just started learning about white holes, so my knowledge is severely limited. It seems I also can't find much about them online that could in any way that answers my question.

Question: If a white hole were to be orbiting a black hole would this create gravitational waves.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30406/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic - I'm asking about them orbiting and its effects. Doesn't this link talk about collision which is surely different from orbiting correctly? Please explain to me what I did wrong. Thanks!!!

Comment: Any 2 bodies orbiting each other create gravitational waves, for example binary neutron stars or binary black holes.