# Can Black hole eat white hole or white hole eat black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, galaxies, white-holes

No light can enter black holes, but is it possible for a white hole to enter a black hole? Or vice versa? Could there be black holes inside the white holes? Or were there black holes inside them that could not hold the black holes because they were pulling everything on themselves and twisted into themselves that over time these white holes exploded and the black holes came out? My point is that is it possible that the early universe consisted of a white hole that contained the entire universe and exploded because of all the energy within it? Or is this just my brain theory?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30406/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I have to say that the question linked to the close reason doesn't really seem to have quality answers, either.

Comment: The exterior metric is exactly the same for a black and white hole. Plus it takes an infinite time for a white hole to start radiating, but the universe is not infinitely old. Thus real white holes do not radiate and therefore cannot be told apart from black holes by *any* external experiment, including a collision. A collision of a black and white hole appears from outside exactly the same as a collision of two black holes. Furthermore, we don’t know if the objects we call “black holes” are not actually white holes. As far as the entire external uninverse is concerned, there is no difference.